# Need to select data in every nth time 30 min, 60 min, 180 min interval

Tags: mysql

I have data in mysql which is stored in every 15 minutes.

```
e.g. 2021-08-24 01:00:01
     2021-08-24 01:15:01
     2021-08-24 01:30:01
     2021-08-24 01:45:01
```

Now I want to select data with every 60 (number is dynamic and can be 15,30,60,180,360 multiple of 15) minute interval.
the expected output is

```
For every 60 minute
| Price |      Datetime        |   
|  5    | 2021-08-24 01:15:01  | -> most recent row
|  3    | 2021-08-24 00:15:01  |
|  2    | 2021-08-24 23:15:01  |
|  4    | 2021-08-24 22:15:01  |
|  6    | 2021-08-24 21:15:01  |


For every 45 minute
| Price |      Datetime        |   
|  5    | 2021-08-24 01:30:01  | -> most recent row
|  1    | 2021-08-24 00:45:01  |
|  2    | 2021-08-24 23:00:01  |
|  3    | 2021-08-24 22:15:01  |
|  5    | 2021-08-24 21:30:01  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are 2700 seconds in 45 min, this is the formula you need

```
select now() RightNow,now() - interval MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()),2700)-1 second per;
```

### Example Output

```
mysql> select now() RightNow,now() - interval MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()),2700)-1 second per;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| RightNow            | per                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2021-08-24 13:59:46 | 2021-08-24 13:15:01 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

### Your Case

```
SELECT Price,`Datetime` - INTERVAL MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Datetime`),2700)-1 SECOND;
```